# Implementing a stack like table with Cassandra (CQL 3)

Tags: stack, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

First of all I request you to please bear with me and I apologise if this is a silly question.

I have a table like this.

```
create table users (
cname text,
--anything else like counter or timestamp
primary key (cname)
);
```

All I need to do is implement a stack like structure with that table.

A number of insert and delete operations will be there.

Problems faced:

1) I tried using timestamps. I successfully inserted using `dateof(now())` but **I just wanted to delete the last 1 record** (???). Also, by making `cname,t` (where `t` is of type `timestamp`) as primary key, I'm having redundant cnames which I don't want.

2) I tried using [counter](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters) but I felt it was complicated. Also, I may have multiple threads or clients performing the insert/delete operations. So, I thought leave it.

3) Also, I will not be knowing the value of cname. So, queries which require key in `where` clause are impossible. So i think I need to change the primary key to some other variable.

Please help me move forward. I'm finding it a bit difficult as there are no good books available for cql to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks and Queues are antipatterns in cassandra ( http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets ) - you can implement them, but you need to understand the internals quite well before you'll be able to do it without making a horrible mistake. It's fairly clear that you're probably not at that level yet.

Is there a reason you think you need to use cassandra for a stack?

Yes, the first part of your primary key (known as your partition key) needs to be something you know, so if you dont know cname, it's probably not a great fit for your primary key. What DO you know about the data/usage patterns? Maybe time buckets?